# A computation using the Ito integral

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

I was assigned this exercise by my Stochastic Analysis Professor.

Exercise.

Let $B$ be a one-dimensional Brownian Motion, and consider the following processes:
$X_t=\int_0^tB_sds\quad Y_t=\int_0^ts^2dB_s$.
Compute, for $s,t\geq0$, $Cov(X_s,Y_t)$.

Solution.

This is how i would solve it.

It is known that the stochastic integral (with respect to the Brownian Motion), as a process, is a martingale. So $Y_t$ is a martingale. It is known that $\mathbb{E}(Y_t)=0$, too. So, using these two facts, we get

$Cov(X_s,Y_t)=\mathbb{E}(X_sY_t)=\mathbb{E}(X_sY_s)\quad s\leq t$.

It is kwown that

$Cov(\int_a^bX_tdB_t,\int_a^bY_tdB_t)=\mathbb{E}(\int_a^bX_tdB_t\int_a^bY_tdB_t)=\mathbb{E}(\int_a^bX_tY_tdt)$ 
whenever the processes $X_t$ and $Y_t$ satisfy some integrability assumptions. So at this point I would proceed like this

$\mathbb{E}(X_sY_s)=\mathbb{E}[\int_0^sB_udu\int_0^sv^2dB_v]=\mathbb{E}[\int_0^s(\int_0^udB_w)du\int_0^sv^2dB_v]=\mathbb{E}[\int_0^s[\int_0^udB_w\int_0^sv^2dB_v]du]=$

$=\mathbb{E}[\int_0^s[\int_0^udB_w(\int_0^uv^2dB_v+\int_u^sv^2dB_v)]du]=\int_0^s\mathbb{E}[\int_0^udB_w(\int_0^uv^2dB_v+\int_u^sv^2dB_v)]du=\int_0^s(\int_0^uv^2dv)du=\frac{s^4}{12}.$

In this way I get the same result my Professor got in the solution he posted on his webpage, nevertheless he procedeed in a different way. Infact, he wrote

$\mathbb{E}(X_sY_t)=\mathbb{E}(X_sY_s)=s^2\int_0^s\mathbb{E}(B_uB_s)du-2\int_0^s\int_0^su\mathbb{E}(B_uB_v)dudv=$

$=s^2\int_0^sudu-2\int_0^s\int_0^s\min(u,v)dudv=\ldots=\frac{s^4}{12}$.

I really don't get this

$\mathbb{E}(X_sY_s)=s^2\int_0^s\mathbb{E}(B_uB_s)du-2\int_0^s\int_0^su\mathbb{E}(B_uB_v)dudv$

while for the rest I'm ok because one of the characterizations of the Brownian Motion is as a gaussian process with mean zero and $Cov(B_s,B_t)=\min(s,t)$.

Thank you all.

Comment: Your third equality, in which you interchange a Riemann and an Ito integral, should be carefully justified.

Comment: Actually I don't know how justify it carefully. Maybe the way my professor worked it out did not require any uncomfortable passage like that, and this is one of the reasons i'd like to understand his solution.

Answer (score 3):

Note that by Itô's formula (applied for $f(t,x) := t^2 \cdot x$), we have

$$s^2 B_s = \int_0^s r^2 \, dB_r + 2 \int_0^s r B_r \, dr.$$

This is equivalent to

$$Y_s = s^2 B_s - 2 \int_0^s r B_r \, dr$$

and that's exactly the identity which your professor used.